# Combine 2 Mysql queries into one

Tags: mysql

i have two queries

1)

```
 SELECT COUNT(room_id) FROM room WHERE hotel_id LIKE '777' GROUP BY room_id
```

2)

```
SELECT COUNT(room_id) FROM orders WHERE hotel_id LIKE '777' AND checkout = '$today'
```

I want to know, if i can create a single query which will return both value.
I tried **JOIN** but, can not get a wanted result. (Do not know about **JOIN** s)

Comment: I don't think the first query really does anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the query you want is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NumRooms, SUM(checkout = '$today') as NumCheckoutToday
FROM orders
WHERE hotel_id LIKE '777' ;
```

Your first query is going to return a list of "1"s for every room in the hotel.  That doesn't seem particularly useful.  I'm guessing you want the actual count.